# Maximum number of lists in Sharepoint

Tags: 2010, list

Currently I have a single list where I store some data for all users. The problem is that the list has scalability issues after 5000 rows. I was thinking to create a list for each user.

How many lists can I create in Sharepoint 2010 ? Is there a limit?  I need to create at least 1 million lists.

What is the recommended approach ?

Thank you

Comment: I couldn't find any limit on number of lists, however you might want to go through this link, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seem 2000 lists is the suggested limit.

See [this page from Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287790.aspx)  for further detail. Note that the limit isn't an "hard limit" but performance seem to degrade exponentially after that point.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

the scalalibity issues are due to poor planning.  With good planning that should not happen, limit is 30 million items per list.

Sharepoint 2010 LIMITs
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787(v=office.14).aspx#ListLibrary

Comment: "You can create very large lists using standard views, site hierarchies, and metadata navigation. This value may vary depending on the number of columns in the list and the usage of the list."   5 columns are too much for 30 mil items ? How it performs with 100k simultaneous read/writes?

Comment: with 30 millions items, 1 server would not be enough and then you need to scale out.   Please check the farm topologies for recommendation based on limits, http://blogs.technet.com/b/schadinio/archive/2010/08/18/sharepoint-2010-technical-diagrams.aspx, look ath the small and medium topologies.  Your Sharepoint will be way too slow specially if the crawl components are on the same WFE.

Comment: i still need to find the maximum # of lists to see if the other approach is better, but links are useful

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262813(v=office.14).aspx explains how to optimize performance

Answer (score 0):

It's actually possible the issues you are experiencing are a result of you having reached the default threshold limit for queries on a SharePoint list. You might need to put indexes on some of your columns as SharePoint will not run any query that results in a table scan affecting more items that you have in the threshold e.g if you wanted to run a query to return a few items but the column you're querying by does not have an index on it, SharePoint will have to scan the entire list to return your result. Now if that list has grown beyond the threshold limit, SharePoint will not allow the query to run.