# maximum theoretical or practical number of libraries in a site collection

Tags: 2013, library

We are reviewing this page:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787(office.15).aspx#ListLibrary

It doesn't seem there are limits to the number of libraries in a site collection, just more of a global size allocation @ the site collection / DB level.

Please advise if we do have any library count limit per site collection.

Thank you!

Comment: Your link is the good one. But I'm wondering : why are you asking this question, curiosity ? or a specific need ?

Answer (score 0):

in theory:

> Maximum no of items including list item and document in  a content
>   database is 60 Million
>
> Maximum no of items a list can have is 30,000,000 per library i.e 30
>   million, so roughly you can have 2 million list in a site collection
>   each list having 30,000,000 items
>
> from support perspective so you can 2 million list in one site in a
>   site collection or divided it into the number of sites you plan to
>   have in you site collection accordinly.

[source](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/aae76e1c-57b5-45f2-b21d-1de1ae83b251/number-of-document-libraries-per-site)

in practice:

> Seem 2000 lists is the suggested limit.
>
> Note that the limit isn't an "hard limit" but performance seem to
>   degrade exponentially after that point.

[source](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/66652/maximum-number-of-lists-in-sharepoint)

Comment: The math in this answer is blatantly incorrect. 2 million lists with 30 million items each are in totalt 60 trillion items, way above the limit of the content database..

Math: lists = L, items = I, Total items = T

T = L * I = (2 * 10^6) * (30 * 10^6) = 2 * 30 * (10^6)^2 = 60 * 10^12 = 60 000 000 000 000.