# Limit of Document Libraries per Site

Tags: 2013, document-library, limitations

Is there a limit of Document Libraries per site?

I was looking for information about it and I just found information about the limit of the items of a Document Library but no the limits of Document Libraries per Site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the official SharePoint Limits and Boundaries

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx#ListLibrary

From this we can make few assumptions and calculate number of libraries per Site Collection ~ 2 Million

[maximum theoretical or practical number of libraries in a site collection](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/110250/maximum-theoretical-or-practical-number-of-libraries-in-a-site-collection)