# SharePoint Online Limit on Number of Libraries

Tags: sharepoint-online

In SPO, what is the limit on the number of libraries in one site?

This thread points to SP on-prem:
[Limit of Document Libraries per Site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/144144/limit-of-document-libraries-per-site)
*Assuming* SPO has a different limitation / threshold.

Not seeing it in the documentation:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/sharepoint-online-service-description/sharepoint-online-limits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I known, there is no hard limit for the number of document libraries you can have on one site.

A library can have up to 30 million files and folders and a list view should not show more than 5000 items.